# Multiple Jupyter recommended?

Tags: homebrew, python

I was having some trouble with `Jupyter` not being able to locate python packages which lead me to find out that I am having 2 installations of it : one in `/usr/local` and one through `homebrew`. Is it recommended to keep both of them? Why? Ideally, it seems to me that having a single installation is cleaner (specially, since there are no back-compatibility issues like with python which may require one to have multiple installations of it).

Output of `where jupyter` :

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/jupyter
/usr/local/bin/jupyter
```

I am running macOS 11.2.3 on MBA with M1.

Comment: None of them is native, both are user-installed. Did you migrate from a previous Mac where jupyter was already installed in /usr/local?

Comment: @nohillside Yes, user-installed, that's what I meant. I didn't migrate. This is my first Mac computer.

Comment: Is the local/bin version a binary or a symlink? If a link, where does it point to?

Comment: @nohillside Using `readlink /usr/local/bin/jupyter; echo $?` I get 1 which means that it is hardlink. Same case for the homebrew one.

Comment: If `readlink /opt/homebrew/bin/jupyter` exits with status code 1 something is wrong (this should be a symlink to the current jupyter version in /opt/homebrew/Cellar).

Comment: @nohillside So, how do I identify it? I have no idea what's going on here. IIRC then I installed `jupyter` through homebrew following this : https://medium.com/@blessedmarcel1/how-to-install-jupyter-notebook-on-mac-using-homebrew-528c39fd530f

Comment: Maybe start with `brew doctor` and fix any issues it reports.

Comment: @nohillside `brew doctor` reports that my system is ready to brew.

Comment: Can you run `ls -l /opt/homebrew/bin/jupyter` to verify that it is indeed a file (and not a symlink)? Also, we can't see into your system and don't know in detail how it got into the state it is. "remove /opt/homebrew and /usr/local and restart the the installation" might be the best answer anybody can give right now

Comment: @nohillside Output is '-rwxr-xr-x  1 MYNAME  admin  245 Apr  5 14:33 /opt/homebrew/bin/jupyter'. I tried removing jupyter through `brew remove/unsintall jupyter` but it doesn't recognise it!

Comment: If you have /opt/homebrew I assume you are on Big Sur. If so how did you upgrade, the /usr/local could well bne from an old homebrew

Comment: @mmmmmm Yes, Big Sur 11.2.3. I upgraded using the regular `brew update` & `brew upgrade` commands and I update my OS using the System Preferences.

Comment: If uninstalling jupyter through homebrew fails, it wasn't installed by homebrew.

Comment: @nohillside even if it is now in a different place - i.e. /opt/homebrew rather than /usr/local ?

Comment: @mmmmmm OP says " I didn't migrate. This is my first Mac computer." so something is broken really bad here. I would just start over, as mentioned above

Comment: He said he upgraded in answer to my question So we have confusion of what exactly has happened. Did Homebrew originally install in /usr/local for Big Sur - I know they had to move to the more sensible /opt/homebrew for Apple Silicon

Comment: If the OP installed Homebrew right after the M1 came out it may have ended up in /usr/local first (which may have resulted in a botched installation). Even that doesn't explain why they got hard links instead of symlinks in the homebrew bin directories.

Comment: @nohillside Indeed, OP (me) did install Homebrew right after M1 came out (around 20 December).